# Nodejs async/await not waiting as expected

Tags: node.js, async-await

I am trying to call an async function in `app.js` to initialize parameters (fetch configuration from AWS, connect to DB, etc.)

This is the `init.js` that does the initialization:

```
const fs = require('fs');
var params_path = process.argv.slice(2);
const paramdata = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(params_path[0]));


module.exports.initApp = async function()
{
    // Retrieve the configuration parameters from AWS
    const aws = await require('./util/configparams').AWS(paramdata);
}
```

This is `configparams.js`:

```
async function AWS(params)
{
        awscredentials = new AWSCredentials(params);
        await awscredentials.initWalletParams();
        await awscredentials.initDbParams();

        return awscredentials;
}
```

`initWalletParams` and `initDbParams` are `async` functions that have `await` statements.

Then this is my `app.js` where I call the init:

```
(async() => {
    init = require('./init');
    await init.initApp();
})();
```

The execution reaches `initApp()` and goes to `await awscredentials.initWalletParams();` function but it does not wait there.
When I run `init.js` by itself the execution happens sequentially as expected but calling in `app.js` `await` is not waiting as expected.
Could someone please help figure this out?
Thank you.

Comment: Anything you want to happen after `await init.initApp();` needs to be in your IIAFE. Anything outside your IIAFE, including below it, will run before the `init.initApp` Promise resolves.

Comment: @Paulpro Thank you. So you mean that all subsequent statements need to be inside the `async()` function in `app.js`?

Comment: Is there a proper way to run an `async` function for initialization without having to put the entire code inside an `async`?

Comment: Everything needs to be in an async function, or in a Promise#then callback (or in another function that is called from one of those places).